# List commands / keywords in a directory sorted by frequency of use

Tags: spacemacs, emacsclient, terminal-emacs

I want to do some refactoring. For that purpose I want to list all keywords grouped and sorted by their frequency of appearance.

That could help me get ideas, which repetitive code I could start abstracting-away.

Is there a way to do this nicely with emacs / elisp?

Comment: The "keywords" being a word list that you already have in a separate file?  And you want to know how many times each of those words appears in some other set of files?

Comment: Yes, think of those text analyzers who let you find the most frequent phrases: https://www.online-utility.org/text/analyzer.jsp

The idea is to search through files in a directory (with subdirectories), do you think that is possible?

Comment: Sure, but I probably wouldn't use elisp to do it.  Is there a particular reason you would like to do it within Emacs?

Comment: No, there is no particular reason I want to do it within Emacs other than convenience